# Carregar imagem sem extensão em webapp

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic

Tenho um webapp feito em Angularjs e Ionic. Em um dado momento carrego imagens de um webservice, no entanto essas imagens não tem extensão, sendo algo do tipo, https://servidor.com/usuario/avatar/128/128. Quando rodo o app no browser, a imagem carrega normal, no entanto quando compilo para Android ou iOS a imagem simplesmente não abre...

Estou carregando a imagem numa tag `<img ng-src="https://servidor.com/usuario/avatar/128/128"/>`

Alguém já passou por isso? Como corrigir?

Abs

Comment: Você deixou o celular com acesso a internet ? Talvez como a imagem está na web o celular necessite estar conectado na mesma. É só uma sugestão , acredito que você já tenha testado isso , mas vai que...

Comment: Deixei sim @Rubens Barbosa, inclusive liberei o acesso a links externos com o plugin cordova Whitelist, tanto que os demais dados são retornados normalmente... Alguma outra sugestão?

Comment: Já tive problema com o ng-src, por incrível que pareça troquei o ng-src por apenas src={{variaval}} e funcionou, não sei por que mas como está funcionando deixei lá

Answer (score -1):

Tente carregar sua img com:

img/image.pngo

invés de

/img/image.png

Tive esse mesmo problema e essa foi a minha solução.